# How to implement the one_done trigger rule for Airflow?

Tags: triggers, airflow

Airflow provides multiple trigger rules except for the **`one_done`** trigger.

*Is there any way, we can implement the **`one_done`** trigger in airflow?*

I need the **`one_done`** trigger rule for the below case:

Let's suppose I have the below tasks dependencies,

```
A >>[B,C,D,E]>>F
```

Task **F** need to be triggered as soon as any of tasks **B** or **C** or **D** or **E** get completed irrespective of the status of `failed` or `success`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do a trick by adding two dummy tasks before `F`, one with the trigger rule `one_success` and the second with the trigger rule `one_failed`, and for F, you should use `one_success`:

```py
A >> [B,C,D,E]
[B,C,D,E] >> Dummy1
[B,C,D,E] >> Dummy2
[Dummy1, Dummy2] >> F
```

When a task finish:

- if its state is `success`, `Dummy1` will be executed and marked as `success`
- if its state is  `failed`, `Dummy2` will be executed and marked as `success`

In the two cases, `F` will be executed

Comment: I guess it will create an issue, let's suppose, task B get failed then it will trigger task F through the Dummy2 Task and next if C gets success then it will trigger Task F again through the Dummy1 Task. That I don't want. The task can not be triggered two times, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: no, it will be run one time, it just does not wait for all upstream tasks to be done, once a of its parent is `success` (`Dummy1` or `Dummy2`), it will be run, and when the second finishes, your run will be marked as `success` without re-running the task `F`

Answer (score 1):

Starting Airflow 2.5.0 a new trigger rule `one_done` was added (see [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/26146), [feature request](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/26099))
This new trigger rule handles your use case without any workarounds.

Comment: need to understand the none_skippeed rule, I guess it will trigger after execution of all upstream tasks. In my case [B, C, D, E] that I don't want. My task F can not wait for all task completion. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @NikhilSuthar see edit